# Handling IS NULL SQL parameters in geoserver

Tags: sql, postgresql, geoserver

I'm creating a SQL layer from postgres database on geoserver using query and applying style on it.

I want to create two layer based on parameter passed into it, currently I'm handling this by creating two separate SQL layers.

First layer:

```
SELECT 
    activity_group_id, activity_name, application_status_code,
    village_code, geom
FROM 
    dbt.dbt_point_primary 
WHERE 
    village_code = '%vinCode%' 
    AND attributes = '%attribute%' 
    AND application_status_code = %statusCode%
```

Second layer:

```
SELECT 
    activity_group_id, activity_name, application_status_code,
    village_code, geom
FROM 
    dbt.dbt_point_primary 
WHERE 
    village_code = '%vinCode%' 
    AND attributes = '%attribute%' 
    AND application_status_code = %statusCode%
    AND activity_group_id = %activity_group_id%
```

While accessing this layer by getMap function I'm passing viewParams

```
&viewparams=vinCode:546748;statusCode:1;attribute:Farmer
```

and

```
&viewparams=vinCode:546748;statusCode:1;activity_group_id:19;attribute:Farmer
```

My concern here is instead of creating 2 separate layer for same expected layer can I handle this into only 1 SQL layer by using `ISNULL` function in the SQL layer.

Does anybody have any source to share?

Comment: where would `IS NULL` come into your queries? Any way you can use any valid Postgresql/Postgis SQL in the creation of your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your parameter is null and if not use it to filter the query

```sql
...
AND (%activity_group_id% IS NULL OR activity_group_id = %activity_group_id%)
```

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by @JGH this is how handled the sql query on geoserver. 
**SQL layer**

```
SELECT 
    activity_group_id, activity_name, application_status_code,
    village_code, geom
FROM 
    dbt.dbt_point_primary 
WHERE 
    village_code = '%vinCode%' 
    AND attributes = '%attribute%' 
    AND application_status_code = %statusCode%
    AND (%activity_group_id% IS NULL OR activity_group_id = %activity_group_id%)
```

to allow null value in **viewparams** change regular expression to **^(?:[\w\d\s]+$)** 
pass viewparams as 
to get ALL activity_group_id 
`&viewparams=vinCode:546748;statusCode:1;activity_group_id:**NULL**;attribute:Farmer`

to get specific layer for activity_group_id 
`&viewparams=vinCode:546748;statusCode:1;activity_group_id:**value**;attribute:Farmer`